# Declaring Variables in Meteor

Tags: meteor

Hi I'm new to Meteor and am trying to understand how to declare variables that are available to all functions in a template. Say I have a single template with a few functions and I want to declare a variable that can be used by all those functions, where do they get defined?

Apologies for the basic question; I've played around with a number of things and can't get it working. Thanks in advance!

```
var foo;
//where do I declare foo??

if (Meteor.isClient) {

Template.myTemplate.events = function () {
    'click div': function() {
        foo = "bar";
    }
}

Template.myTemplate.events = function () {
    'click span': function() {
        if (foo === "bar") {
            console.log("gettin jiggy with it");
        }
    }
})
}
```

Comment: at least for the example you are showing you should really use session variables instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variables declaration is fine, you just used the `Template.myTemplate.events` function incorrectly. Here is the corrected version:

```
var foo;

if (Meteor.isClient) {

Template.myTemplate.events({
    'click div': function() {
        foo = "bar";
    },
    'click span': function() {
        if (foo === "bar") {
            console.log("gettin jiggy with it");
        }
    }
});
}
```